# How to embed a ZMachine in a webapp?

Tags: z-machine

I am planning to create an webapp which shall implement ZMachine Games. I would like to choose python and the google app engine. Something like Parchment would be ok too. How do I have something which will handle the ZIL games?

Comment: [Parchment](https://code.google.com/p/parchment/) appears to supports z-code, are there any ZIL games that *weren't* released in z-code?

Comment: I've tried three times to edit this into something that makes sense. I can't. Would the OP please clarify their intent?

Comment: For the record I just tested it ([URL](https://iplayif.com/?story=https%3A%2F%2Fifarchive.org%2Fif-archive%2Fgames%2Fzcode%2Fzdungeon.z5)) and Parchment does in fact play ZMachine games :)